# Subsetting columns in a dataframe in r based on indexes selected by user

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have to provide user with the list of all available columns in the dataframe and users should enter all the indexes for the columns which needs to be subset. Now I want to use this user input of indices for subsetting the dataframe

Sample steps
(1) Display and ask user to select the column names from dataframe (df)
(2) user selects: 1,2,3,4,5
(3) Create a dataframe with only columns 1,2,3,4,5 from the large dataframe,df

Comment: you can use subset with column index using base R

Comment: So what is the question here? Are you asking how to subset a `data.frame`? That's covered by practically *any* introductory R tutorial. Are you asking others to write a shiny app (or something similar) for you to do what you're describing? In that case, SO is not the right forum. SO is not a free code writing service. The community helps with *specific* coding issues.

Comment: I assume you're building  a shiny app. Could you add sample code showing what you have done and why or how it has failed? It however does seem like homework.

Comment: I was able to subset directly by passing column indices but I wasn't sure how to ask user to mention the indices numbers and then use those set of indices in creating the subset. It is not for shiny application. I have created feature selection algorithms and I want to use the columns selected in feature selection to run my parameter tuning. To subset those columns, I wanted user to input the indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the following code to solve my problem.

## Subset the required elements

```
test_function<-function(data)
{ 
  prompt<-paste(which(colnames(data)==names(data)),'-',names(data))
  print(do.call(cat, c('Input column index numbers',as.list(prompt), sep="\n")))
  return(data[,c(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(readline('Enter the column index number'),split=',')) ))])
}

subset_for_tuning <- test_function(Datadf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any sample data to work with, it's difficult for the community to help you. Please read [how to post your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I've written a snippet based on my understanding of your problem, but this is not verified. Do the necessary modifications.

```
library(stringr)
cols <- colnames(inputdf)
cat(paste("Available column names are :", cols))
cat("Enter your choices seperated by ',':")
choices <- readline()
choices <- str_split(choices, pattern = ",")
choices <- as.numeric(unlist(choices))
outputdf <- subset.data.frame(inpudf, select = choices)
```